# AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions not prompting for permission

Tags: cocoa, accessibility

I'm trying to use the Accessibility API and have this code:

`NSDictionary *options = @{(__bridge id) kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt : @YES};
BOOL accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options);`

This always returns no, however it does not prompt the user for permission nor does it display the app's name in System Preferences > Security & Privacy. What do I need to test this? I could try and add the debug version manually into System Preferences but how do I know that this will work properly when released to the public? Is there any way to test this out? I am not seeing any prompt at all.

Comment: I tried manually adding the app to the list in System Preferences but AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions always returns false. Can't seem to test this basic feature.

Comment: Does Xcode have persmission?

Comment: No, and it didn't ask if Xcode should (?). I also tried 'installing' the app under /Applications (the debug version) and tried running from there, no luck.

Comment: Your code works on my Mac (OS X 10.10).

Comment: Did you manage to get this sorted? I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: Is the debug build properly bundled?

Comment: @KaneCheshire Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I didn't. I can't even remember exactly why I needed it now 

Answer (score 11):

From Apple Developer Forums:

> It appears, in 10.13.3 at least, that applications which are using the app sandbox will not have the alert shown.  If you turn of app sandbox in the project entitlements then the alert is shown. - haikuty

Comment: More discussion can be found here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24288.

Comment: Worth noting that Sandboxed apps signed with Mac Development or official Mac App Store certificates WILL show the Accessibility prompt. But Developer ID signed apps will not show the prompt. This applies to 10.15 and 11.0 and possible 10.14 too.

Comment: That's weird. I'd expect that during development (using the "Development" signing certificate) the Mac Development certificate is used for signing.
Nope. Does *NOT* work.