# detect when use allow the application to use universal access

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, accessibility, cgeventtap

I am developing an utility for OSX which need to use Universal Access (accessibility and event tap).

I am using AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions to check if the application is allowed. I am checking this state every second (pooling) in order to detect when user is allowing it.

Unfortunately, AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions is always returning false, even when the application has been allowed.

I know it is possible because others applications like popclip  are doing it but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Added: code

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)kCFBooleanTrue, kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt, nil];
if (!AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((CFDictionaryRef)options) ) {
    while (!AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(NULL)) {
        NSLog(@"Still not allowed");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
    }
    NSLog(@"user just allowed the application");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"App is already allowed");
}
```

Comment: And if you restart the app? Do you run in Xcode?

Comment: I tried both in Xcode (in that case I allow Xcode) or starting the app from the finder. If I restart the app, in that case it works fine but the user experience is not very good :(

Comment: I tried this (OS X 10.11) and it works. Show us your code.

Comment: I've edited the initial question to include the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: actually, issue is with [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];.....

Comment: I used a timer.

Comment: I have an issue with this. Sometimes it will show correctly true/false however closing the app out and re-running the app prompts the user for permissions when it is already set. Any idea?

Comment: In my case `AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames` didn't give any attributes. I solved it by disabling **App Sandbox** in the projects `.entitlements` file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901425/5233188